# Load balancer with Laravel Forge got 404 CSS

Tags: php, css, laravel, load-balancing

I have two servers which host two identical Laravel app. Let's say Server One and Server Two. And there is Load Balancer let's call this LB Server.

I set up that on Laravel Forge. But, when I point the domain to LB. I got random 404 CSS not found. I use Laravel Mix and compile them when I do the deployment. Since the two servers got different deployment the CSS versioning is different and also the JS.

What happened is if I call the domain and if I keep refreshing the server, I got 404 CSS. Since LB is doing Round Robin Load Balancing.

The problem is when I call the domain name the LB server serves to Server One. After I keep refreshing, the LB server serves to Server Two. That time, the CSS is still calling the Server One CSS.

How can I fix this?

> Notes: I know I should put my CSS/JS/Images should put to S3 or CDN. 
>   Can't use those options for now. I don't
>   want to put my compiled CSS to git versioning as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your deployment: Generate the files only once and sync them to the servers instead of generating them on every production server each (rsync for example).

Another (not elegant) way could be to use sticky sessions, the LB will set a cookie and allways route a user to the same backend afterwards (see your LBs docs).